# Null pointer exception error ANDROID

Tags: java, android, oop

I created a onDestroy method for my filter searchbar and i met with a small prob.

here is my logcat:

```
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem/com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.employer.HomepageEmployerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3655)
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3673)
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014):     at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.employer.HomepageEmployerActivity.onDestroy(HomepageEmployerActivity.java:340)
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3642)
09-01 01:55:40.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1014):     ... 11 more
```

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    searchBarEmployer.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher); <--- LINE 340
}
```

****EDIT
THIS IS MY LOGIN CODE That will switch to homepage after the user entered the correct credentials.

```
public class LoginEmployerActivity extends Activity {
Button btnLoginEmployer;
Button btnLinkToEmployerRegisterScreen;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView loginErrorMsg;
TextView forgotPassword;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_CNAME = "cname";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_employer);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmployerEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmployerPassword);
    btnLoginEmployer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginEmployer);
    btnLinkToEmployerRegisterScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToEmployerRegisterScreen);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);
    forgotPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_forgetPassword);

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLoginEmployer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Checking for server respond
                new LoginEmployer().execute();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToEmployerRegisterScreen
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            RegisterEmployerActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            });

    // Link to forgot password link
    forgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Switching to forgot password screen
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ForgotPasswordEmployerActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

// Background ASYNC Task to login by making HTTP Request
class LoginEmployer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    // Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginEmployerActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    // Checking login in background
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                EmployerFunctions employerFunctions = new EmployerFunctions();
                JSONObject json = employerFunctions.loginUser(email,
                        password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandlerEmployer dbe = new DatabaseHandlerEmployer(
                                    getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json
                                    .getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            employerFunctions
                                    .logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            dbe.addUser(
                                    json_user.getString(KEY_NAME),
                                    //json_user.getString(KEY_CNAME),
                                    json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),
                                    json.getString(KEY_UID),
                                    json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                            // Launch Employer homePage Screen
                            Intent homepage = new Intent(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    HomepageEmployerActivity.class);

                            // Close all views before launching Employer
                            // homePage
                            homepage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(homepage);

                            // Close Login Screen
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            // Error in login
                            loginErrorMsg
                                    .setText("Invalid username/password");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I hope your `searchBarEmployer` has been initialised and referenced properly.

Comment: how do i initialised that? searchBarEmployer is my editText

Comment: Please check my answer below. I have given the code there. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your `searchBarEmployer` has been initialised and referenced properly.

```
EditText searchBarEmployer ; // outside onCreate, global to class
```

Inside onCreate(),

```
searchBarEmployer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextIdInXML);
```

Also,

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    searchBarEmployer.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Comment: yup. trying this changes now.

Comment: yup i did all these. Now have no error but after i cannot get to the homepage. after login should go to the homepage but it went back to the login page.

Comment: And make sure you are using the correct id of the EditText in findById(). It is the id that is there in your XML file where you have defined the layout of the EditText. Also make sure that super.onDestroy() is the very last statement in your function.

Comment: @SarahPhil : If you want to go to the homepage, you must define the intent that takes it to that page and start the intent.

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(context, Homepage.class); intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Then there must be some other problem with your code in starting the intent. It is advisable that you ask only one question per post here. So, if your Null Pointer exception is solved now, I suggest you make a new question regarding starting the intent and put the code there. :)

Comment: i updated the login code above. dont mind help me take a look?

Comment: Your intent code looks correct to me. Did you try raising a Toast at that specific line to check if your login logic is correct or not ? I mean, there could be something wrong with JSON or integerParsing operations maybe. Try making a Toast at that line and see.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220848/error-switching-to-homepage-after-login

Comment: No problem! You are welcome! And I will surely look into the question! :)

Answer (score 1):

You did it wrong. If you override `onCreate()` (or in general, constructor alike method) then rule of the thumb is to call `super.onCreate()` **FIRST** (to init all stull super class may need etc) then do your stuff. But if you override `onDestroy()` (or in general destructor alike method), then rule of the thumb is to all the cleanup things in opposite order you did in `onCreate()`. Clear own stuff first and call `super.onDestroy()` as one of **LAST** thing. Doing it otherwise (like you did) may cause many problems as super class could simply clean many things up (like internal variables, references etc), already and your code will simply crash. Reaarange your `onDestroy()` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    searchBarEmployer.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

There'is also option that your `searchBarEmployer` is simply null, so this could possibly be safer:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if( searchBarEmployer != null ) {
      searchBarEmployer.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please place a debug point and make sure that `searchBarEmployer` is not null.

In case it is `null` due to some steps performed earlier place a null check before this statement.

```
if( searchBarEmployer != null ) {
// Place operation here...
}
```

Also you should move

```
super.onDestroy();
```

as the last statement of the method.

**EDIT**  I meant...

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if( searchBarEmployer != null ) {    // <---- PLACE NULL CHECK
      searchBarEmployer.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    }
    super.onDestroy();  // <--- LAST STATEMENT
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by move that to the last statement?

Answer (score 0):

please  initialise searchBarEmployer if necessary.
like if searchBarEmployer is a text view declare it top, then do searchBarEmployer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id....); and so on and then use it.

Avoid using 
TextView searchBarEmployer=null; 
kind of approach.