# Send Intent from doInbackground to the MainActivity

Tags: android

I am trying to send intent from the doInBackground method of the inner class MyAsyncTask of PostData to the inner class LocationListen of my MainActivity but I am getting

> Multiple markers at this line: 
>       The constructor Intent(PostData.MyAsyncTask, Class) is undefined -The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type PostData.MyAsyncTask

How can I sent the ArrayList by intent and receive it correctly?

I appreciate any help.

in doInBackground method- of inner class MyAsyncTask- in the PostData class:

send Intent:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> routes = data.getRoutes(); //contains [7,31]

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); //The first error here
        intent.putExtra("stop_route" ,routes);
        startActivity(intent); //The second one here.
```

in the onLocationChanged method- of the inner  LocationListen in the MainActivity class:

receive Intent:

```
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        b.getIntegerArrayList("stop_route");
```

The PostData class:

```
public class PostData {
String jSONString;

public PostData() {
    super();

}

public String getjSONString() {
    return jSONString;

}

public void setjSONString(String jSONString) {
    this.jSONString = jSONString;
}

public void post_data(String jSONString) {
    this.jSONString = jSONString;
    new MyAsyncTask().execute(jSONString);
}

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
    final Context mContext;

    public MyAsyncTask(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("The output of : doInBackground "
                    + params[0]);

            URL myUrl = new URL(
                    "https://blabla-blabla.rhcloud.com/webapi/data");
/connection.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.connect();
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    conn.getOutputStream());
            // write to the output stream from the string
            wr.writeBytes(params[0]);

            wr.close();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            StopsJSON data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), StopsJSON.class);

            ArrayList<Integer> routes = data.getRoutes();

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext , MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("stop_route" ,routes);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);

            System.out.println("The output of the StringBulder before "
                    + routes);
            System.out.println("The output of the StringBulder: "
                    + sb.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                    return null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting intent after Async task gets over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220848/starting-intent-after-async-task-gets-over)

Comment: `this` is not a `Context`. Pass a `Context` into `MyAsyncTask`.

Comment: @Sebastin: I am getting `Context cannot be resolved to a variable`? I set it like this `Intent intent = new Intent(Context , MainActivity.class);`

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to launch MainActivity from inside the AsyncTask? Is the AsyncTask inside MainActivity as well?

Comment: @lemuel: Yes I am trying to launch the MainActivity inside the AsyncTask. No, the AsyncTask is inner class of another class `PostData`

Comment: What's the superclass of PostData? If it extends Activity, you can use `Intent intent = new Intent(PostData.this , MainActivity.class);`

Comment: The same way you can use `PostData.this.startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 0):

Store the context as field in your asynTask:

```
final Context mContext;
public MyAsyncTask(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    ...
```

Intent needs a context as first parameter(your first error, see [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E))):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
```

startActivity(intent); is a method of Context, so you need your Context again(your second error, see [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent))):

```
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Now I am getting an error where I am invoke the execute method in the PostData class. `The constructor PostData.MyAsyncTask() is undefined` at this line `new MyAsyncTask().execute(jSONString);`

Comment: sure, you have to call it like this PostData.MyAsyncTask(this). If it is inside an Activity. Or PostData.MyAsyncTask(getActivity) if you call it inside a Fragment.

Comment: That's because you now have `MyAsyncTask(Context)` as your constructor, not just `MyAsyncTask()` anymore. Pass a context into it.

Comment: I have Added the the whole PosData class to the  question code since I have tried it to call it like that and I am getting `The method MyAsyncTask(String) is undefined for the type PostData`?

Comment: Then add context to the parameter of ```public void post_data(String jSONString, Context context)```.... and then call new ```MyAsyncTask(context).execute(jSONString);```

Comment: @EarlOfEgo: I think it works in the PostData class no error but the problem now in the inner class `LocationListener` where I am invoke the `post_data` method ``sender.post_data(jSONString, context);`` I am getting  `context cannot be resolved to a variable` ham I implemented an contructor for  inner class `myLocationListener` like in the Asyntask class as the fololwing `final Context bContext; public myLocationListener(Context context){bContext = conext;}` here I am getting this error`conext cannot be resolved to a variable` as well as in the onCreate() method in the MainActivity class

Comment: as I wrote in my previous comment, you have to call it with ```this``` inside an activity or ```getActivity()``` inside a fragment. ```sender.post_data(jSONString, this);``` but that are basics.